# Whitespace Tabs Show Differently in gVim on Windows/Linux versus MacVim on Mac OS

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, macvim, macos

I am having difficulty getting MacVim to behave and look the same as gVim on Windows or Linux. Here's an example:

gVim on Windows:
[image: GVIM on Windows]

MacVim on Mac OS:
[image: MacVim on Mac OS]

These are viewing precisely the same file. The gVim on Windows look is what I want.

Note: the MacVim version appears to be computing the beginning of the line incorrectly, as it should be directly under the 'I' as the very first character in the file. On a number of the later lines, you simply can't navigate to the very beginning of the line, either with the `0` command, or with the usual `h` key.

Here are the vimrc files:

gVim on Windows:

```
set guifont=Courier_New:h9:cANSI:qDRAFT
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=m
set showmode
set cursorline
set showcmd
set autoindent
colorscheme murphy
set noswapfile
syntax on
set number
set mouse=a
map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
set numberwidth=8
set ruler
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
autocmd FileType python set columns=80
:imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
:nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
```

MacVim on Mac OS:

```
set fileformat=mac
set guifont=CourierNewPSMT:h10
set showmode
set cursorline
set showcmd
set autoindent
colorscheme murphy
set noswapfile
syntax on
set number
set mouse=a
map <ScrollWheelUp> <C-Y>
map <ScrollWheelDown> <C-E>
set numberwidth=8
set ruler
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
autocmd FileType python set columns=80
:imap <c-s> <Esc>:w<CR>a
:nmap <c-s> :w<CR>
```

Finally, here's the text of the text file, as copied from MacVim:

```
I.   33: Introductions

 A. 33: Meyer: Scientific and Philosophical Introduction: Defining Theistic Evolution
    1. 34: Evolution #1: "Change over Time"
       a.  34: Can be simply "change over time". Has little or nothing to do with the modern "neo-Darwinian" theory of evolution.
       b.  34: In evolutionary biology, "change over time" can refer to the idea that the life forms we see today are different from the life forms that existed in the distant 
               past.
       c.  35: "Change over time" can also refer to observed minor changes in features of individual species - small-scale changes that take place over a relatively short 
               period of time: microevolution.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: The file you pasted has no tabs. Something is very wrong if spaces are showing up as different widths on MAC.

Comment: Right, I'm replacing all tabs with spaces - at least I thought I was. What would be wrong?

Comment: Put `set list listchars=tab:>-` in your vimrc to confirm that there are no tabs. (Tabs will show up as ">---".)

Comment: @Tumbler41: Hmm. I'm not seeing tabs showing up as >---, even after deleting the line with tabstop and so on, and restarting MacVim. It still seems to be replacing tabs with spaces.

Comment: Followed the procedure here: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting. Didn't help. Problem appears to be in base vim, not in MacVim.

Comment: Trying `brew install vim` to see if a replacement install helps...

Comment: Doesn't help. The brew install behaves precisely the same.

Comment: I'm in the process of posting on the vim_use Google Group. Maybe something will come of that.

Comment: What does it look like if you run the following command? `set list listchars=space:.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an answer on the vim_use Google group. It came down to priorities, and which vimrc is being used. For MacVim, there's a `.gvimrc` as well as a `.vimrc` file, and the `.gvimrc` file was overriding the `.vimrc` settings. Once I copied the `.vimrc` file to `.gvimrc` with the following changes in particular, I got the same view:

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab
```

The `.gvimrc` file had `tabstop=8`, which was the primary problem. There were also tabs in the actual file, which I replaced using the following command:

```
:1,$s/\t/    /g
```

Comment: Two notes: 1) Instead of duplicating `.vimrc` into `.gvimrc` you may want to simply clear out `.gvimrc` and use it only for settings that you exclusively want have in MacVim/GVim but not in console Vim. Should speed up startup by not setting everything twice, might avoid some issues that I think can sometimes occurs with setting certain things twice, and for things you want in both MacVim/GVim and console Vim, you only need to make a change in one place. 2) You might be interested in the [`:retab`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:retab) command for files with mixed indentation characters.

Comment: @8bittree: Great, thanks for those tips!